# Exception occurred Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: c#, arrays, ascii

I get the following error when running my code:

Exception occurred Index was outside the bounds of the array.

My code is below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
namespace ASCII

{
    class CharacterFrequency
    {
        private char ch;
        private int frequency;

        public char Ch
        {
            get { return ch; }
            set { ch = value; }
        }
        public int Frequency
        {
            get { return frequency; }
            set { frequency = value; }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public string InputFileName = "wap.txt";
        public string OutputFileName = "Output.txt";
        public string FilePath = "";

        public static SortedDictionary<char, ulong> Count(string stringToCount)
        {
            SortedDictionary<char, ulong> characterCount = new SortedDictionary<char, ulong>();


            foreach (var character in stringToCount)
            {
                if (!characterCount.ContainsKey(character)) // added character to dictionary if only character is absent in charactercount
                {
                    characterCount.Add(character, 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    characterCount[character]++; // increemetned count
                }
            }
            return characterCount;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            CharacterFrequency obj = new CharacterFrequency();
            StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(p.OutputFileName);

            try
            {
                p.InputFileName = args[0]; // get input
                p.OutputFileName = args[1]; // get output
                p.FilePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\" + p.InputFileName; // get file path
                if (File.Exists(p.FilePath)) // checked if file exist
                {
                    string data = File.ReadAllText(p.FilePath); // read the data in string
                    var count = Program.Count(data); // pass the string to count method
                    foreach (var character in count)
                    {
                        streamWriter.WriteLine(character.Key + "(" + (int)character.Key + ")" + "\t" + character.Value); // write data to output file
                    }
                    streamWriter.Close();
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Please provide input File"); // if input file absent sent message to user to place input file
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception occured " + ex.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The program is supposed to read an ASCII text file and count the number of times each character appears in the text file. It should output a text file with this information and the character frequency objects should be stored in array. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Which line of code throws the exception?

Comment: I am not sure the error is displayed to the console and the program runs successfully and builds but does not work properly.

Comment: You need to debug the code to understand which line throws the exception

Answer (score 0):

The only lines I see that could possibly throw that exception are these:

```
p.InputFileName = args[0]; // get input
p.OutputFileName = args[1]; // get output
```

The `args` array has the arguments from the command line. So when you run this, are you passing arguments in the command line? like:

```
program.exe input.txt output.txt
```

But you are declaring variables for them:

```
public string InputFileName = "wap.txt";
public string OutputFileName = "Output.txt";
```

So maybe this is what you're intending?:

```
p.InputFileName = InputFileName;
p.OutputFileName = OutputFileName;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static SortedDictionary<char, ulong> Count(string stringToCount)
{
   var characterCount = new SortedDictionary<char, ulong>();

   foreach (var character in stringToCount)
      if (!characterCount.ContainsKey(character))       
         characterCount.Add(character, 1);
      else
         characterCount[character]++; //

   return characterCount;
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{

   var filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);  
   var inputFileName = Path.Combine(filePath, args[0]);
   var outputFileName = Path.Combine(filePath, args[2]);

   // read data, count chars
   var count = Count(File.ReadAllText(inputFileName)); 

   // create output
   var outPut = count.Select(x => $"{x.Key}\t{x.Value}");

   // write it
   File.WriteAllLines(outputFileName, outPut);

}
```

So

- if you need to combine paths, use `Path.Combine`
- If you need to project or convert things use `Select`
- If you need write some lines `File.WriteAllLines`

Obviously this lacks error checking, and what you pass in.